# Receiving data from bluetooth, how to "clear" on CR+NL but with bytes

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Forms App that basically displays some numbers from some sensors that send data in hex value bytes. I also have a Thermometer that communicates via string.
**BACKGROUND INFO**
So I had an issue with the Thermometer "data feed" where sometimes it would send something like 56.385 but my software was displaying 6.385 or .385 or some version of a truncated string because some timing got weird and so I started filtering my "received data" by looking for that "CR+NL" that it sends with every value (per the manual). After adding code to do that I stopped having that issue.
After long periods of data logging using the sensors that use bytes I came across the same issue, sometimes my values would be wrong and would get timeouts of data-points for 4 - 10 seconds (expecting 2-per second) because the received "chunk" of data was truncated.

---

TL;DR: I want to filter my "receiveddata" and clear my buffer every time I find a CR+NL (carriage return + newlinefeed). I can do it using strings, but I dont know if it works the same with bytes.

For my "datareceived" to the Thermometer I have this:

```
    private void ThermometerDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string dataReceived = "";
try
            {
                dataReceived = HH42Port.ReadExisting();
                stringBuffer += dataReceived;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

if (stringBuffer.EndsWith("\r\n"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(stringBuffer);
                    stringBuffer = stringBuffer.Substring(0, stringBuffer.IndexOf("\n"));
                    StringDataNeedsParsing(HH42ID, "::" + stringBuffer);
                    stringBuffer = "";
                }
```

Now, this is my "byte" version but it doesnt work. I have the same issue where I sometimes get truncated values and go up to a few seconds without any values (when values are "full" a message of "full packet received" is printed, see bottom for console output.

```
         //According to the manual for the byte-device:
         //Every reading starts with 0x02[...DATA...]7E+CR+NL
        //#define CR 0x0D
        //#define NL 0x0A
    private bool didLineEnd(List<byte> listCheck)
    {
        byte lastByte = 0x00;
        byte second2LastByte = 0x00;
        if(listCheck.Count > 2)
        {
            lastByte = listCheck[listCheck.Count - 1];
            second2LastByte = listCheck[listCheck.Count - 2];
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (lastByte == 0x0A && second2LastByte == 0x0D)
        {
            return false;
        } else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
   private void DirectModule_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string resultSeed = "";
        byte data;
        rxDataBufferRawSeed.Clear();
        Thread.Sleep(25);
        if (isModuleHardwired)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USB Module Data Received:");
            while (directUSBPort.BytesToRead != 0 && didLineEnd(rxDataBufferRawSeed))
            {
                data = (byte)directUSBPort.ReadByte();
                rxDataBufferRawSeed.Add(data);
            }
            resultSeed = ByteArrayToString(rxDataBufferRawSeed.ToArray());
            resultSeed = String.Concat(resultSeed.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
            Console.WriteLine("SEED RESULT: "+resultSeed);
        }
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT (Showing only TWO good readings, even though I received multiple, the only one that was parsed is the one that says "Full packet received")

```
USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0xCDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B9BA0DC2200000C220000041B5AB7DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8A9CDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4985DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8061DC2200000C220000041B47CBDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B798CD41B4985DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BB6C3DC2200000C2200000E2247E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B6502D00C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BF367D41B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BC449DC2200000C220000041B4B3DDC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B6A26DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4985DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B558FDC2200000C220000041B42A1DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BA783D41B200EDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BB6C3DC2200000C2200000092D2F7E
Full Packet Received
Parsing Module Readings from module
USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B8
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B8 
Length: 18

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x061DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BF6C2D0041B6502D00C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BA5D1DC2200000C220000041B4B3DDC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B9321DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4CF6DC2200000C220000041B3D74DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B99EED41B2385DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BA936DC2200000C2200000C4217E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B5747DC2200000C2200000C2
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B5 74 7D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 
Length: 51

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x200000C220000041BEB04D41B5FDCDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BBF38DC2200000C220000041B368CDC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B857FDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4CF6DC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B94D4D41B2385DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BC449DC2200000C22000005DAB7E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B7EABDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE29
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B7 EA BD C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 BE 29 
Length: 81

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0xED41B2C2DDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BBF38DC2200000C220000041B4613DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B7B42D00C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4CF6DC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B94D4D41B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BA0BADC2200000C22000009E5D7E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B5747DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE29ED41B5FDCDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE7A8DC2200000C220000041B368CDC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B6D93DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B5747DC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8C51D41B2385DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE29EDC2200000C2200000C3B17E
Full Packet Received
Parsing Module Readings from module
USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B8061DC2
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B8 06 1D C2 
Length: 27

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BFD76D41B634CDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE7A8DC2200000C220000041B558FDC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B6D93DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B3F2EDC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8C51D41B2385DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BBF38DC2200000C22000001F7C7E
Response received: 
Length: 0

The thread 0x5b4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B6502D00C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BE29ED41B558FDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BA5D1DC2200000C220000041B5747DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8E04DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B2DE9DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B916CDC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8733D41B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BB1A
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B6 50 2D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 BE 29 ED 41 B5 58 FD C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 BA 5D 1D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B5 74 7D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B8 E0 4D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B2 DE 9D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B9 16 CD C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B3 4D 3D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 B8 73 3D 41 B3 BB AD C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 BB 1A 
Length: 585

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0xFDC2200000C2200000D3FA7E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B5747DC2200000C2200000C2200000
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B5 74 7D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 
Length: 60

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0xC220000041BD528D41B558FDC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BAE4CDC2200000C220000041B4985DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8061DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B5747DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B4B3DDC2200000C220000041B34D3DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8C51D41B2385DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BBD88DC2200000C2200000A41E7E
Response received: 
Length: 0

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x0200C8000141B8061DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BD528D41B5AB
Response received: 00 C8 00 01 41 B8 06 1D C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 C2 20 00 00 41 BD 52 8D 41 B5 AB 
Length: 93

USB Module Data Received:
SEED RESULT: 0x7DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BBF38DC2200000C220000041B4985DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B8061DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B2DE9DC2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B6F48DC2200000C220000041B42A1DC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041B7EABD41B3BBADC2200000C2200000C2200000C220000041BAFFEDC2200000C220000009987E
Response received: 
Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Serial Port data often comes in bits and pieces, you need to keep a cache of what you've received so far between subsequent calls to `DirectModule_DataReceived`. In my experience, you can also get multiple readings in the same call, so you need to be aware of that too. A simple way would be to keep your buffer array live between calls, and check after each call if you have a full message to parse.

```
private void DirectModule_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isModuleHardwired)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("USB Module Data Received:");
            while (directUSBPort.BytesToRead != 0)
            {
                var data = directUSBPort.ReadByte();
                rxDataBufferRawSeed.Add(data);

                if(data == 0x0A
                      && rxDataBufferRawSeed.Count > 2
                      && rxDataBufferRawSeed[rxDataBufferRawSeed.Count - 2] == 0x0D
                      && rxDataBufferRawSeed[rxDataBufferRawSeed.Count - 3] == 0x7E)
                //You have a full packet; process it here
                //ProcessBytes(rxDataBufferRawSeed);
                
                //and then reset
                rxDataBufferRawSeed.Clear();
            }
        }
```